# how to insert svg element into group with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have some SVG code embedded in HTML and I need to add several polygons to the existing SVG with javascript. The problem is that the SVG that exists (that I am adding to) is in a group (g tag) and because of layering, I need to add the new polygons to specific places in that group. I've been writing javascript for a few years now, but I am just starting to learn SVG and I don't know how to add elements to a specific place in the SVG DOM with javascript. My comment below explains why this is different than a previously asked question.

For example:

```
<g id="group1">
    <rect x="20" y="50" width="700" height="20" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
    I need to add polygons here.
    <rect x="20" y="140" width="700" height="20" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
</g>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use javascript to insert an svg use element into an svg group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463072/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-insert-an-svg-use-element-into-an-svg-group)

Comment: @rkm_Hodor That question is very similar to mine, but is different because I am trying to insert an element to a specific place in the group and NOT just append to the end of the group.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

> ```
> var insertedNode = parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
> ```
>
> If referenceNode is null, the newNode is inserted at the end of the list of child nodes.